# Spring 3 and JSON possible to convert manually?

Tags: json, spring-mvc

I have following question. Spring gives us a great opportunity to build AJAX with JSON as return object. But what if I want to convert some object by hand in the code? Can I just call some Springs method  and make converion instead for doing it by hand or use additional library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can.

Just define MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter bean in context:

```
<bean id="MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
```

And you can use it methods to convert.
More, you can define your own Jakson objectMapper for it:

```
<bean id="MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter" class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter">
        <property name="objectMapper" ref="objectMapper"/>
    </bean>
<bean id="objectMapper" class="org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper"/>
```

And use this objectMapper to custom convertations.